# Splitting up a data frame for decision tree learning using stratified sampling

Tags: r, dplyr, decision-tree

I would like to create a training and a test sample set using stratified sampling. I tried looking around but all the packages I found return a data frame instead of an expression. The tree package I am using to build the tree requires the subset to be given as an expression.

Example code:

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
library(dplyr)

Carseats <- Carseats %>% mutate(High = factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")))

set.seed(2)
train_sample <- sample(nrow(Carseats), nrow(Carseats) * 0.7)
carseats_test <- Carseats[-train_sample,]

tree.carseats <- tree(High~ . -Sales, Carseats, subset = train_sample)
```

Is it possible to modify the above code so the sampling is done using stratification?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
library(dplyr)

Carseats <- Carseats %>% mutate(High = factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")))

mean(Carseats$High == "Yes")
[1] 0.41

train_sample <- Carseats %>%
tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
group_by(High) %>%
sample_n(0.7*n()) %>%
mutate(rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%
pull(rowname) 

carseats_test <- Carseats[-train_sample,]
mean(carseats_test$High == "Yes")
[1] 0.4132231

tree.carseats <- tree(High~ . -Sales, Carseats, subset = train_sample)
```

Comment: As I tried to describe, the tree() function does not accept a data frame as input. This looks like it is a data frame to me.

Comment: sure. just add a rowname then.